# Oauth and scopes and its correct use

Tags: angularjs, security, oauth, scope, owin

May be I am missing something here but what the point of client requesting scope?

What I mean is that when a client request a token he/she can say "I want everything" i.e. read/write/delete/update etc.

In reality, user might only have read access. So what's the point of requesting these in scopes? or its not a good practice/idea to put these in scope? If not then what do you really use it for?

I have seen in some places where it's used for Email, Username while others its used for repo:read, repo:write...

Isn't Authorization server going decide what permission the user has?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question fully but here goes. In a typical OAuth scenario, there's the:

- OAuth provider - has the protected resource, issues access tokens to resource (e.g. Google)
- End user - owner of resource (e.g, Google user)
- Relay party - uses OAuth to access protected resource from provider on behalf of end user (e.g, some random app that does something with your google profile)

When you use the relay party's application, it needs to get your information from the OAuth provider. Most providers have different levels or "scopes" of access to the end user's information - it's usually not an all or nothing access. The relay party must define the scope of access, and ask the OAuth provider, the provider presents the scope of access request to the end user, and finally the end user can decide whether to grant the relay party that scope of access or deny it.

So without scope, how can a relay party request a granular level of access?

Comment: "So without scope, how can a relay party request a granular level of access?" ... I see what you mean. But on other hand relay party can just give access to user (which he/she is entitled to). It seems like replay party can ask for access "X" which user don't have access and the Oauth provider is going to deny it (seems like an extra check). But I also see your point where User have access to 100 things but if you narrow down it via scope for a particular request then its limited and access token becomes light weight.

Comment: "I see what you mean. But on other hand relay party can just give access to user (which he/she is entitled to)" - but the relay party doesn't grant access, it's the provider, and only at the user's discretion.